# How to convert a JSON lib formatted JSON date to a Javascript Date

Tags: javascript, json

Sourceforges JSON-lib (http://json-lib.sourceforge.net) produces a JSON date format like this:

```
{
    "date":10,
    "day":5,
    "hours":0,
    "minutes":0,
    "month":5,
    "nanos":0,
    "seconds":0,
    "time":1307660400000,
    "timezoneOffset":-60,
    "year":111 //this is 2011
}
```

Is there an easy way to convert this into a Javascript date object or should I just go through and set all the variables on the date object manually?

I've searched all over to find this with no luck! (apologies if the answer is lying around somewhere, I just can't seem to find it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like time is the epoch in msec, so you can just do: `new Date(object['time'])`

You will need to of course parse this into an object first.

Comment: Easy when you know how! :) I'll accept this as the answer as soon as Stack Overflow lets me...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the [json-lib project home](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) page , there are no example explain the the process of **Date**.But as soon as you search json-lib's API,you will finally get the answer.

Here you can use this method below to process **java.util.Date** class. You can define your own format pattern and use the **JsonConfig** to register a custom **JsonValueProcessor** that used to process the **Date** class.

```
public static final JSON serializerObjWithFormatDate(Object javaObj){
    
    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    
    final SimpleDateFormat fm =  new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    
    JsonConfig jsonCfg = new JsonConfig();
    
    jsonCfg.registerJsonValueProcessor(Date.class, new JsonValueProcessor() {
        
        @Override
        public Object processObjectValue(String key, Object value, JsonConfig cfg) {
            if (value == null) {  
                  return "";  
            } else {  
                  return fm.format((Date)value);
            }
           
        }
        
        @Override
        public Object processArrayValue(Object date, JsonConfig arg1) {
             return fm.format((Date)date);  
        }
    });
    
    return JSONSerializer.toJSON(javaObj ,jsonCfg);
}
```

The param **javaObj** is the java object who has **Date** class instances.

May it be helpful .